# Calling abstract base class method with a dynamic value

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a method from an inherited abstract base class with a dynamic variable, but it fails with an overflow exception.

A runable version (with a bool value) can be tested at:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/hSfsZl

A runable version that crashes (with a dynamic value) can be found at:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/qXlMZD

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    dynamic processed = true;
    // this works though
    //bool visible = true; 
    var data = new TemplateData<string>();
    var dataProcessor = new TemplateDataProcessor<string>(data);
    dataProcessor.Process(processed);

    Console.WriteLine(data.Processed);
}

public class Data : IData
{
    public bool Processed { get; set; }
}

public interface IData
{
    bool Processed { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DataProcessorBase<TData, TDataBuilder>
    where TDataBuilder : DataProcessorBase<TData, TDataBuilder>
    where TData : IData
{

    public TData Data { get; set; }

    public DataProcessorBase(TData data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public TDataBuilder Process(bool value)
    {
        Data.Processed = value;

        return this as TDataBuilder;
    }
}


public abstract class DataProcessor<TData, TDataBuilder> : DataProcessorBase<TData, TDataBuilder>
    where TDataBuilder : DataProcessor<TData, TDataBuilder>
    where TData : IData
{
    public DataProcessor(TData data)
        : base(data)
    {

    }
}

public interface ITemplateData<T> : IData
    where T : class
{
    string Template { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateData<T> : ITemplateData<T>
    where T : class
{
    public string Template { get; set;  }

    public bool Processed { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateDataProcessor<T> : DataProcessor<ITemplateData<T>, TemplateDataProcessor<T>>
//public class TemplateDataProcessor<T> : DataProcessorBase<ITemplateData<T>, TemplateDataProcessor<T>>
    where T : class
{
    public TemplateDataProcessor(ITemplateData<T> data)
        : base(data)
    {
    }
}
```

Calling `dataProcessor.Process(processed);` with a boolean value works as expected, but calling it with a dynamic variable equal to true is throwing the exception. In addition, inheriting from the base abstract class fixes the problem

```
public class TemplateDataProcessor<T> : DataProcessorBase<ITemplateData<T>, TemplateDataProcessor<T>>
```

Why this isn't working? In addition, why inheriting from the base class - `DataProcessorBase` - is working even with the dynamic value? What is the problem with the following inheritance that breaks the code:

```
public abstract class DataProcessor<TData, TDataBuilder> : DataProcessorBase<TData, TDataBuilder>
```

Can this be fixed by meeting all of the following requirements:

1. Do not move any methods from `DataProcessorBase` to `DataProcessor` class or change their code, e.g. changing to `Process(dynamic value)` is not allowed.
2. The call to `dataProcessor.Process` will be made using dynamic, i.e. the end user of the API cannot be forced to use bool instead of dynamic.

Comment: The code on dotnetfiddle runs for me, printing "True" - no exception. Are you sure that exact code fails? Are you able to simplify the code any further, e.g. removing the interfaces, possibly removing the generics? The simpler you can make the code, the better - as well as giving us an example that really fails, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet the code intentionally has the `dynamic visible = true;` commented as it will crash. Here is an updated version that crashes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qXlMZD . I will also update the original post with this version.

The generics and the interfaces cannot be removed as this is a requirement. The problem seems to be connected with this implementation, so it is as simplified as possible. There are constraints that cannot be removed.

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce it now. I still strongly suspect it can be simplified - I'll see if I can do so. (Just because you need the interfaces and generics for the real code doesn't mean that's required in order to diagnose the problem.)

Comment: Interestingly, it works on .NET Core 2.2, but fails on .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Hmm, the issue seems to be triggered by/related to the curiously recurring template/generics pattern. Removing this pattern from the code (quick'n'dirty dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwrNYv) makes the issue "go away"...

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in .NET, basically. Here's a rather shorter repro: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TAnJge

Comment: Indeed, I was testing on .NET 4.5.2 and it fails, but it works with .NET Core 3.0.. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be issue in .NET itself - in the dynamic dispathc, as look the callstack:

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be issue in .NET itself - in the dynamic dispathc, as look the callstack:     it just repeats

```
TypeManager.SubstTypeCore(type, pctx)
TypeManager.SubstTypeArray(taSrc, pctx)
TypeManager.SubstTypeCore(type, pctx)
AggregateType.GetBaseClass()
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, atsOuter, typeArgs)
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, typeArgsAll)
SymbolTable.GetConstructedType(type, agg)
SymbolTable.LoadSymbolsFromType(originalType)
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, atsOuter, typeArgs)
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, typeArgsAll)
TypeManager.SubstTypeCore(type, pctx)
TypeManager.SubstTypeArray(taSrc, pctx)
TypeManager.SubstTypeCore(type, pctx)
AggregateType.GetBaseClass()
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, atsOuter, typeArgs)
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, typeArgsAll)
SymbolTable.GetConstructedType(type, agg)
SymbolTable.LoadSymbolsFromType(originalType)
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, atsOuter, typeArgs)
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, typeArgsAll)
TypeManager.SubstTypeCore(type, pctx)
TypeManager.SubstTypeArray(taSrc, pctx)
TypeManager.SubstTypeCore(type, pctx)
AggregateType.GetBaseClass()
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, atsOuter, typeArgs)
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, typeArgsAll)
SymbolTable.GetConstructedType(type, agg)
SymbolTable.LoadSymbolsFromType(originalType)
TypeManager.GetAggregate(agg, atsOuter, typeArgs)
AggregateSymbol.getThisType()
SymbolTable.AddAggregateToSymbolTable(parent, type)
SymbolTable.LoadSymbolsFromType(originalType)
SymbolTable.GetConstructedType(type, agg)
SymbolTable.LoadSymbolsFromType(originalType)
SymbolTable.GetConstructedType(type, agg)
SymbolTable.LoadSymbolsFromType(originalType)
SymbolTable.CreateInheritanceHierarchyList(type)
SymbolTable.PopulateSymbolTableWithName(name, typeArguments, callingType)
PopulateSymbolTableWithPayloadInformation(payload, callingType, arguments)
BindCore(payload, parameters, args, deferredBinding)
Bind(payload, parameters, args, deferredBinding)
BinderHelper.Bind(action, binder, args, arginfos, onBindingError)
CSharpInvokeMemberBinder.FallbackInvokeMember(target, args, errorSuggestion)
DynamicMetaObject.BindInvokeMember(binder, args)
InvokeMemberBinder.Bind(target, args)
DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(args, parameters, returnLabel)
CallSiteBinder.BindCore<System.Action<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, Program.TemplateDataProcessor<string>, object>>(site, args)
UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2<Program.TemplateDataProcessor<string>, object>(site, arg0, arg1)
Program.Main(args)
```

I'd report it to Microsoft